# How to select the first suggestion in the address bar auto suggestion?

Tags: firefox

On Internet Explorer 8 if we type stuff in the address bar and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the browser will navigate to the very first suggestion. Is there a way we can do the same thing on Firefox 3.6.6?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe once you start typing and the history list shows up, just hit "Tab" and then Enter.

Comment: +1 this is easier for me... :)

Answer (score 4):

Type, then ***Down Arrow*** and ***Enter***

Comment: Although this is true, it does take my hands away from the home row which I would rather not do. The tab+enter is more fluid.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Firefox addon:

> [Enter Selects](https://addons.mozilla.org/af/firefox/addon/7423/)
>   Press enter in the AwesomeBar to select the first result (without pressing down)